# $2^{nd}$ order ODE $4x(1-x)y''-y=0$ with $y'(0)=1$ at $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

it has two singular point $x_0 =1$ and $x_0=1$
I rearrange the equation to 
$$y'' - \frac{1}{4x(1-x)}y =0$$
and by $v(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4x(1-x)}$ are analytic at $x_0$ for both $0$ and $1$;

that is, $x_0=1,0$ are regular singular points,

so that, I can find a solution by series... (Here, what kind of method should I apply..?)

I just tried the Method of Frobenius:

where the indicial equation is $$r(r-1)-1=0$$ and $r_1=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$and $r_2=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$ where $r_1 - r_2 =\sqrt5$ is not ingeter.

I require to use $$y_1 = x^\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$$
$$y_2 = x^\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n$$
it seems not sensible to solve this with $x^\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$ trem,

should I keep working with Method of Frobenius...?... or in any other way..?

Comment: Make sure that you got the right indicial equation.

Comment: ye.. it's an issue.. because I cannot find the formula of indicial equation for equation with $4x(1+x)y''$ and I applied the $r(r-1)+p_0 r +q_0 =0$ to seek the indicial equation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you use Frobenius method, you write $$y=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$$ $$y'=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ia_ix^{i-1}$$ $$y''=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i(i-1)a_ix^{i-2}$$ Now, for $$4x(1-x)y''-y=4xy''-4x^2y''-y$$ and replacing, you have $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}4i(i-1)a_i x^{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(4i(i-1)+1)a_i x^{i}$$ So, by identification of the coefficients for the same power in both lhs and rhs, you arrive to $$a_{i+1}=\frac{4i(i-1)+1}{4i(i+1)}a_i$$ The initial condition gives $a_1=1$. So, you have all coefficients (I suppose that you noticed $a_0=0$).

**Added after OP's work and comment**

Less lazy than I am, the OP reported in a comment to this answer that

$$a_n=\frac{(4*2*1+1)(4*3*2+1)...(4(n-1)(n-2)+1)}{4^{n-1}n!(n-1)!}$$ (in the comment, I identified a small typo for th power of $4$ in the denominator). So the problem was to simplify the numerator and the overall expression. The result is $$a_n=\frac{\Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\pi  (n-1)! n!}$$ and then $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n=x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};2;x\right)$$

Comment: by this relation, there is 
$$a_2=\frac{1}{4*2*1}$$
$$a_3=\frac{4*2*1+1}{4*(3*2)}a_2=\frac{4*2*1+1}{4^2(3*2)*(2*1)}$$
$$a_4=\frac{4*3*2+1}{4*(4*3)}a_3=\frac{(4*2*1+1)(4*3*2+1)}{4^3(4*3*2)(3*2*1)}$$
$$a_n=\frac{(4*2*1+1)(4*3*2+1)...(4(n-1)(n-2)+1)}{4^nn!(n-1)!}$$

Here, how to simplify this term$(4*2*1+1)(4*3*2+1)...(4(n-1)(n-2)+1)$

Comment: This is a very good point ! Let me a few minutes and I should add to my answer if I find something. Cheers.

Comment: Done ! See pmy answer. As I said, in the denominator, it is $4^{n-1}$ and not $4^n$. Congratulations for having developed and asked the good question ! Cheers.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici, what would happen if we substitute $i=0$ in your recurrence relation? I'm afraid your equation is a particular case for one of the roots of the indicial equation, which are $s=0$ and $s=1$. In this case, we have patology and Frobenius only provides one of the two parts of the solution. I will provide more detail in my answer, which I'm about to write down. Cheers!

Comment: thanks. tried it to simplify that part... but there is still somewhere goes wrong... I cannot get the $\pi$ in the final solution...

Comment: @Dmoreno. I was just thinking about that just right now ! You are perfectly right. By the way, everything I did was for $i>0$. I really wait for your answer because I think that the solution is very complex. Thanks for pointing my mistake. Cheers :-)

Comment: There it is @ClaudeLeibovici, I hope you find it helpful! However, I'm afraid I will not be able to find a closed form for the sum.

Comment: @leave2014. The $\pi$ disappears because of the numerator $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi }$,$\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$,$\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})=\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi }}{4}$ and so on

Comment: cool... thanks.. i forgot to divided by the remain terms..

Answer (score 2):

Frobenius method reads, after proving that $x=0$ and $x=1$ are regular singular points:

$$y(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} b_n x^{n+s}, \quad s \in \mathbb{C}, \quad b_0 \neq 0.$$

Substitute this in the ODE, assuming uniform convergence to have:

$$ 4\sum^\infty_{n=0} b_n (n+s)(n+s-1)x^{n+s-1}-4\sum^\infty_{n=0} b_n (n+s)(n+s-1) x^{n+s} - \sum^\infty_{n=0} b_n x^{n+s} = 0, $$

group the second and third terms and write the first one conveniently to come up with:

$$ 4 \sum^{\infty}_{n=-1}b_{n+1} (n+s+1)(n+s)x^{n+s} -\sum^\infty_{n=0} b_n\left( 4 (n+s)(n+s-1)- 1\right) x^{n+s} = 0,$$ for which we can say that for:

$$ \begin{align}
n = -1: & \quad 4 b_0 s(s-1) = 0 \implies s_1 = 1 \text{ or } s_2 = 0 \\
n \geq 0: & \quad b_{n+1} = \frac{1+4(n+s)(n+s-1)}{4(n+s+1)(n+s)} \, b_n
\end{align}
$$

Since $|s_1-s_2| \in \mathbb{N}$ we have *pathology* (of course, note that $s=0$ is not a valid value of $s$ in the recurrence relation) and we must therefore choose $s = s_1 = 0$ for which we will be able to write one part of the solutions, say $y_1(x)$, while the other one remains unkown until variation of parameters is applied, i.e., setting $y(x) = A(x) y_1(x)$.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

---

If you write $y_1(x) = b_0 x \, (1+c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \ldots + c_n x^n) = b_0 x \, (1+P(x))$, where $c_i = b_i/b_0$ and $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that $P(0) = 0$, then after applying VOP you seem to get the following:

$$ y(x) = A_1 y_1(x) + A_2 \underbrace{ y_1(x) \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2 (1+P)^2} }_{y_2(x)}, $$

where it is convenient to recall that:

$$ (1+P)^{-2} = 1-2P+3P^2 - 4P^3+ \mathcal{O}(P^4) $$

so you can ultimately express $y_2(x)$ as a power sieres as well (see @ClaudeLeibovici's comment below).

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer clarifies a lot. Cheers :-)

Comment: You're welcome, mister. It seems that you are right too and $x \  {}_2F_1(1/2,1/2,2,x)$ is a solution of the ODE. The other part of the solution seems to be related with the Meijer-G funcion, which I have no idea how can be derived from this.

Comment: I just saw that monster arriving I don't know where from ! Un abrazo !

Comment: Haha! Igualmente, caballero!

Comment: The solution seems to be $$-c_1 x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};2;x\right)-\frac{\left(c_1+1\right)
   G_{2,2}^{2,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2} \\
 0,1
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{G_{2,2}^{2,0}\left(0\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
 0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks all.. it looks really difficult to get the solution... b.t.w...I think the condition y'(0)=1 could cancel out one of the constant...

Comment: No, it is already included (notice that you only have $c_1$ and no $c_2$ while a second order differential equation). Don't worry : what Dmoreno gave as an answer is the end of the story ! Cheers.

Comment: aha..that is...sorry about this mistake....But. In the end of the question ... there are two asking..."What is the radius of convergence of your solution and why was this expected? Comment on why only one initial condition was required to fully specify the solution."... which seems that we may able to get all constant?

Comment: Frobenius ensures a solution on $x \in [0,1]$, i.e., in between the two singular regular points (you could have expanded the solution about $x=1$ too). Regarding the specification of the initial values, the question is surely referring to the singular character of the other part of the solution when $x$ approaches to the origin. The initial condition must be replaced then by the solution to be bounded, setting the corresponding constant to zero. After that you can apply the other initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{(4*2*1+1)(4*3*2+1)...(4(n-1)(n-2)+1)}{4^{n-1}n!(n-1)!}=\frac{4^{n-2}(2*1+\frac{1}{4})(3*2+\frac{1}{4})...((n-1)(n-2)+\frac{1}{4})}{4^{n-1}n!(n-1)!}=\frac{(2*1+\frac{1}{4})(3*2+\frac{1}{4})...((n-1)(n-2)+\frac{1}{4})}{4*n!(n-1)!}$$

Thanks, I just tried it again..for this part

$$I=(2*1+\frac{1}{4})(3*2+\frac{1}{4})...((n-1)(n-2)+\frac{1}{4})$$

$$I=\prod_{n=3}^{+\infty}[(n-1)(n-2)+\frac{1}{4}]$$$$=\prod_{n=3}^{+\infty}[n^2 - 3n +\frac{9}{4}]$$$$=\prod_{n=3}^{+\infty}[(n-\frac{3}{2})^2]$$

$$I=\Gamma^2(n-\frac{3}{2}+1)=\Gamma^2(n-\frac{1}{2})$$

substitute this back, there is $$a_n=\frac{\Gamma^2(n-\frac{1}{2})}{4*\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n)}$$

where has a difference of $\pi$ and $4$ of denominator..

b.tw..the computer also gives $\pi$... how does this comes?