# Use Frobenius Series Method to Solve $x^2y''+(x^2+\dfrac{5}{36})y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone use Frobenius series method to solve this differential equation step-by-step for educational purposes?

$$x^2y''+(x^2+\dfrac{5}{36})y = 0$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote something of no interest ! I apologize. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

**General steps:**

1. Show that $x = 0$ is a *regular singular* point of the differential equation.
2. Expand the solution as a power series about $x = 0$, i.e.: 
   $$ y(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n x^{n+s}, \quad s \in \mathbb{C}, \quad a_0 \neq 0  $$
3. Introduce this information into the ODE and find $s$ as the solution of the indicial equation and check for patologies ([***link 1***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911569/2nd-order-ode-4x1-xy-y-0-with-y0-1-at-x-0/911918#911918) and [***link 2***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903118/solving-the-differential-equation-9x1-xy-12y4y-0/903160#903160)).
4. Find $a_n$ if possible or, at least, a given recurrence relation of the form $a_{n+1} = a_n f_n$.
5. If the second part of the solution is required, apply the method of variation of parameters (this would give you the particular solution of your ODE too, [***link 3***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652362/find-the-form-of-a-second-linear-independent-solution-when-the-two-roots-of-indi/652468#652468)).

Any doubts, let me know!

Cheers.